# Laravel PHP - Using Route Parameters within a string

Tags: php, laravel, query-string

This is my first attempt at working with Laravel and PHP, so let me know if I'm way off here.

Currently the /groups route outputs all groups in json format, but I would like to be able to utilize route parameters so I can make ajax requests to the groups route such as:

```
fetch('https://my-website/groups/4/1/0')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
    data = myJson;
  });
```

The database I am querying in the Laravel route below has the fields "Ministry_ID", "Day_Of_Week, and "Gender" - My thought was that I could insert the parameters into the `filter` method, but the array just returns [false] if I do that.

```
Route::get('/groups/{ministry?}/{dayOfWeek?}/{gender?}', function ($ministry = null, $dayOfWeek = null, $gender = null) {
    $mp = new \MinistryPlatformAPI\MinistryPlatformTableAPI();
    $mp->authenticate();
    $groups = $mp->table('Groups')->select('*, dp_fileUniqueId AS FileID')->filter('Congregation_ID = 1 AND End_Date > GETDATE()')->orderBy('Start_Date DESC')->get();

    return response()->json([$groups]);
});
```

Comment: It seems like `$groups` is getting set to `false`. Looking at the code in the [`smadeira/ministry-platform-api`](https://github.com/smadeira/ministry-platform-api/blob/master/src/MinistryPlatformTableAPI.php#L412-L463) package, it looks like when `->get()` returns false, there was a curl error. The error message can be seen using the `errorMessage()` method. What error message do you see if you put `dd($mp->errorMessage());` before the return?

Comment: Also, the posted code doesn't actually show you using the parameters in your query. Can you post the code giving you the issue?